# Pandas: return first row where column value satisfies condition against a list of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` and a list of floats `T`. `df.B` is a time series of values sorted in chronological order, where the 0th index is the most recent timestamp and the last index is the oldest timestamp.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4], 'B': [5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8]})
T = [t1, t2, ..., tn] # floats
```

**What I am looking to do**

I would like to compare the values of column `B` against the list of values `T`, one `t` at a time, and return the first row of `df` that satisfies the condition against `t`. By first row of `df` I mean walk through the timeseries (essentially) and find the first instance in time where the values in `df.B` become larger than the value `t` for any `t` in `T`.

**What I've attempted:**

```py
df.loc[df.apply(lambda x: x.B >= T, axis=1)]
# => TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

df2 = df.query('B >= @T')
# => 'Lengths must match to compare'

[ df[df['B'] >= t] for t in T ]
# => Technically this works and then I can iterate again to retrieve the first row, but I get the warning -- pydevd warning: Computing repr of a (list) was slow
```

**EDIT, an example:**

```py
T = [3.5, 4.5, 8.0, 8.5, 10.0, 11.0]
df.B = [5.5, 8.8, 6.6, 7.7]

# I'm hoping that the expected output would have the rows corresponding to the following values in `df.B`:
[7.7, 7.7, 8.8, 8.8, None, None]
```

Comment: Can you post expected out put ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort values in column B, and then use [`numpy.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
import numpy as np
sorted_values = np.sort(df.B)
np.append(sorted_values, np.nan)[np.searchsorted(sorted_values, T)]
# array([5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 7.7, nan, nan])
```

To get data frame rows, first find the indices:

```
indices = np.searchsorted(df.B, T)
indices
# array([0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4], dtype=int32)
```

Then retrieve corresponding rows:

```
[df.iloc[i] if i < len(df) else None for i in indices]

[A    1.1
B    5.5
Name: 0, dtype: float64, A    1.1
B    5.5
Name: 0, dtype: float64, A    1.1
B    5.5
Name: 0, dtype: float64, A    3.3
B    7.7
Name: 2, dtype: float64, None, None]
```

Comment: OP accidentally over-simpified; they describe the `df` dataframe having multiple columns, and wanting the entire row, not just the `B` column.

Comment: `and return the first row of df that satisfies the condition against t`

Comment: `I'm hoping that the expected output would have the rows corresponding to the following values in df.B:`

Comment: @MatBailie This is correct, thank you. Also if this makes it any easier, the values of `B` are a timeseries already sorted by timestamp, where index 0 corresponds to the most recent timestamp and index -1 corresponds to the oldest timestamp.

Comment: It should be similar once you find the first indices of the corresponding value

Comment: @Psidom I updated my post with a bit more detail and also changed the example to represent column B as a timeseries, just a heads up. Looking at your post now

Comment: The update should work the same, just need to make sure sort column B before searchsort. Also `I'm hoping that the expected output would have the rows corresponding to the following values in df.B:` How do you want to store those rows ? Does a list of rows work ?

Comment: @Psidom Ok great, and yeah a list of rows works